# How can I extract multipart RAR files using the command line unrar.exe?

Tags: command-line, extract, rar

Is there a way to extract all RAR files using `unrar.exe` via the command line without passing it each part?

I have lots of multipart RAR files in mixed formats: `.part1.rar`, `.part2.rar` or `.rar`, `.r00`, `.r01`, etc.

Is there a trick I'm missing or this is something only possible from WinRAR (where you just right click Extract and it knows to extract from the other parts as well)?

Answer (score 82):

I've had this very problem before and here is the answer.

```
unrar x filename.part1.rar
```

Comment: If the archive contains a file foo in the directory bar it will be extracted like that under SUSE. Under Red Hat it will become a file called bar/foo for a pity.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is an old question, but I did it with just the following command, using UNRAR 4.10 freeware

```
unrar e filename.rar
```

This handled the multiparts just fine.

Comment: Strangley, in Debian, the unrar package was able to extract my multi-part rars, but the unrar-free was not. This is a bit confusing, because running the unrar command from the unrar package (which is supposedly not free) states that it is UNRAR 4.10 freeware as you mentioned. Thank you, I have been unable to get this working for quite some time.

Comment: To follow up, in Debian, if you don't see a package called 'unrar', make sure you're including contrib and non-free in your apt sources. Unrar is a non-free package.

Comment: You can use the free (as in freedom) unar too as foolows; `unar filename.rar`

Comment: unar doesn't work for me with split archives (on arch) at all, only unrar does. (7zr too doesn't)

Answer (score 2):

Coming back to this in 2023, with Ubuntu 22.04, neither of the other answers worked for me. `unrar` said "Skipped" with the `e` option, and simply "Failed" with the `x` option.

However, `unar filename.part1.rar` worked perfectly.

Comment: All the same with my Fedora system and split archives too.  Guess this is part of the generic GUI utility and wasn't aware of the CLI portion yet.  Too bad 7z(a) doesn't work with the rar format like it does on Windows, making me use more tools this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unrar x filename.part[0|00]1.rar`, this will extract your files with full path.

Using `unrar e filename.part[0|00]1.rar` will just extract without full path.

Comment: Same answers were given more than 12 years ago !